# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'matrix[0][0]' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a matrix (array of arrays) of boolean values which I want to show in a form and then submit after changing. I have problems rendering this and I have no more ideas why it is not working. Can anybody give me an advice?

My Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/konfiguration")  
public class VerteilungController {

    @ModelAttribute("matrix")
    public List<List<Boolean>> getVerteilungenMatrix() {
        List<List<Boolean>> result2 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < kategorien.size(); i++) {
            result2.add(new ArrayList<>());
        }
        //...
        return result2;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/verteilung", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("matrix", getVerteilungenMatrix());
        return "konfiguration/verteilung";
    }
}
```

The form:

```html
<form id="verteilung_form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/verteilung"
    th:action="@{/konfiguration/verteilung}"
    th:object="${matrix}">

    <table  class="table-hover">
        <tr th:each="row: ${matrix}">
            <td th:each="value: ${row}">
                <input type="checkbox" th:field="${matrix[__${rowStat.index}__][__${valueStat.index}__]}"/> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div >
        <button th:text="#{button.save}" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="save">Speichern</button>
        <button th:text="#{button.reset}" name="reset" class="btn btn-default">Zurücksetzen</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Openening the page I get

> Exception: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputCheckboxFieldAttrProcessor'

And in the log

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'matrix[0][0]' available as request attribute

Comment: What is `kategorien`? I don't see its definition anywhere.

Comment: It is not relevant for this. Its size is greater than zero. `result2` is filled with nonnull Booleans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misused `th:object` and `th:field`. `th:object` stands for **command objects** which represents the entire form.

> Command object is the name Spring MVC gives to form-backing beans, this is, to objects that model a form’s fields and provide getter and setter methods that will be used by the framework for establishing and obtaining the values input by the user at the browser side.

On the other hand `th:field` *does all the heavy work of binding your input with a property in the form-backing bean.* Values inside `th:field` should point to a field of the object from `th:object`.

> Values for th:field attributes must be selection expressions (*{...}), which makes sense given the fact that they will be evaluated on the form-backing bean and not on the context variables (or model attributes in Spring MVC jargon).

Please check it out [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#creating-a-form).

So back to your code. To fix it you should create a form-backing bean class and provide the matrix as a field inside that class, for example:

```
public class FormBean {

    private List<List<Boolean>> matrix;

    FormBean() { }

    public FormBean(List<List<Boolean>> matrix) {
        this.matrix = matrix;
    }

    public List<List<Boolean>> getMatrix() {
        return matrix;
    }

    public void setMatrix(List<List<Boolean>> matrix) {
        this.matrix = matrix;
    }
}
```

Next please provide object of `FormBean` as a model attribute. When you provide method marked as `@ModelAttribute` then assignment to a model will be done for you. Update your controller body to the following:

```
@ModelAttribute("formBean")
public FormBean getFormBean() {
    return new FormBean(getVerteilungenMatrix());
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/verteilung", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showPage() {
    return "konfiguration/verteilung";
}

private List<List<Boolean>> getVerteilungenMatrix() {
     List<List<Boolean>> result2 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < kategorien.size(); i++) {
            result2.add(new ArrayList<>());
        }
        //...
        return result2;
}
```

Finally please update your form to the following:

```
<form id="verteilung_form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/verteilung"
            th:action="@{/konfiguration/verteilung}"
            th:object="${formBean}">

            <table  class="table-hover">
              <tr th:each="row: *{matrix}">
                <td th:each="value: ${row}">
                            <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{matrix[__${rowStat.index}__][__${valueStat.index}__]}"/> 
                    </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <div >
                <button th:text="#{button.save}" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="save">Speichern</button>
                <button th:text="#{button.reset}" name="reset" class="btn btn-default">Zurücksetzen</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Now everything should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. It works :). I was not aware that there should always be bean-like objects, hoped there is a way to put simple objects in it. So I have to wrap my matrix, no problem.